# Обращение к элементам формы родительского класса

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt

Qt Designer генерирует при изменении формы новый файл, затирая старые изменения добавленные в ручную поэтому возникает потребность все изменения вынести в отдельный файл. В файле создаю класс формы, унаследовав старую, но при попытке обратиться к ним во время компиляции появляется ошибка (данный атрибут не найден).

```
# parent class 
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.resize(550, 366)
    self.btn_connect = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.btn_connect.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(440, 250, 101, 41))
...
# child class
class Terminal(Ui_MainWindow):
    def setupUii(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow2")
    def add_function(self):
        Ui_MainWindow.btn_connect.clicked.connect(self.start) # error AttributeError: type object
                                                    #'Ui_MainWindow' has no attribute 'btn_connect'
```

Как обращаться к элементам к элементам формы из дочернего класса?

Comment: В `Terminal` раз переопределяете методы нужно вызвать родительские через `super().` И не `Ui_MainWindow.btn_connect`, а `self.btn_connect`

Comment: @gil9red можете примерно набросать, что имеете ввиду? Ui_MainWindow менял на super() тот же результат

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow


# parent class
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(550, 366)

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.btn_connect = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_connect.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(440, 250, 101, 41))


# child class
class Terminal(Ui_MainWindow):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        super().setupUi(MainWindow)
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow2")

    def add_function(self):
        self.btn_connect.clicked.connect(self.start)

    def start(self):
        print('!!!!')


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Terminal):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.add_function()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Правильно говорите, нужно было инициализировать сперва родительский класс super().setupUi(MainWindow) этой строчкой

Comment: @helldrg, пожалуйста :)